# Why script element created via innerHTML does not get executed when appended to DOM, while the same script created via document.createElement does?

Tags: javascript, dom

(Please do not mark this question as a duplicate to [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) because it is not.)

I wonder why a script element created via innerHTML does not get executed when appended to DOM:

```
container=document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML='<script>alert()</'+'script>';
document.body.appendChild(container.firstChild);
```

... while the same script created via document.createElement gets executed when appended to DOM:

```
script=document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML='alert()';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

It looks to me as inconsistency: in both cases I append a script element (which looks the same), so I do not understand why appending the same script gives different results depending on how this script was generated.

Comment: I know you requested this not be marked as a duplicate, but it _is_. A quick Google search shows this question has been asked and answered several times already.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a 'script' tag, the browser evaluate the script expression but when you create a 'div' tag, even if a script is inside the browser won't evaluate that script.

**By default, when you append an element after the DOM loads, the browser won't check/run if you add a script inside UNLESS it is a script pure element.**

Comment: Script inside a div also works, as long as it is created via createElement:
container=document.createElement('div');
script=document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML='alert()';
container.appendChild(script);
document.body.appendChild(container);